# AR with sqlite3: Does setting limits on columns have any effect on db size?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sqlite, rails-activerecord

Im a bit new to AR and Sqlite. I'm working with a big dataset and struggle to figure out what's good practice for optimizing db speed and size.

Eg. I store a one byte integer in a column, does it help anything to declare the column as:

`table.integer :field, limit: 1`

Does this help sqlite save space?

Comment: Setting a limit requires that the text `(x)` is stored in the database, so it wastes space. ☺

Answer (score 1):

From the [fine SQLite manual](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html#storage_classes_and_datatypes):

> **2. Storage Classes and Datatypes**
>
> Each value stored in an SQLite database (or manipulated by the database engine) has one of the following storage classes:
>
> - [...]
> - **INTEGER**. The value is a signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8 bytes depending on the magnitude of the value.
> - [...]

So the storage requirements for a value in SQLite depends on the value itself rather than the column type. Your `:limit` option will be completely ignored by the SQLite driver, similarly `:limit` is ignored for strings as well since SQLite doesn't have `char(n)` or `varchar(n)` types, it just has `text`.

The SQLite type system is fairly loose, reading the entire documentation section on [Datatypes in SQLite](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html) would be a good idea.

Comment: Thanks, I read that documentation, so I wanted to confirm my interpretation. It's not always easy to be sure about how using activerecord influences things. AR docs won't tell you for example that setting limits makes no sense for SQLite.

Comment: The phrase "AR docs" is being generous :) Rails documentation in general is very thin on important details IMO.